# Django runserver hangs on Apple M1 macbook

Tags: python, django, docker, apple-m1

I have django 3.2.12 application. It is running in docker with image python:3.9.12-slim-buster.

When I'm accessing my app through web browser, it often hangs for some time (request pretty always takes exactly 5s - weird).

This happens on chrome, firefox, safari. But only on Macbook with M1 CPU, on intel works fine.

This problem only exist on runserver, it doesn't exist on gunicorn.

The only solution, which I found, is to add '--nothreading' but this is not really a solution.

Do you maybe know what can be an issue here?

Comment: Have you added a profiler to see what it's spending the time on?

Comment: I added silk, and it doesn't show that request are 5s long, it shows normal time like 30ms (even, if from the browser network we can see that this request took 5s).